# Single user authentication across all subdimains in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have

www.abc.com
Sub1.abc.com
Sub2.abc.com
Sub3.abc.com

And so on...

How can I have a user once authenticated on any site be also authenticated on all sites

Much like google services eg: maps, gmail, docs etc... Once authenticated, automatically authenticated on all services.

What are my options? Mulrisite ? And how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/23449/single-user-registration-to-access-all-sites-in-wordpress-multisite-network

Multisite User Management

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/multisite-user-management/